# Sql correct use of STR, CONVERT and NVARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been doing a course on Datacamp and got a question below, 
my answer appears to be correct and gives a correct result, however it is marked as wrong. What is wrong with it?

Use STR, CONVERT, and NVARCHAR(30) where appropriate to display the first name, employee ID and birthdate (as Unicode in ISO 8601 format) for each employee in the Employees table.

Each result should be a single string in the following format, where each <> is replaced by the appropriately converted value:

<> has an EmployeeID of <> and was born <>
Your submission should exactly match the format given above.

My answer:

```
SELECT FirstName + ' has an EmployeeID of ' 
+ STR(EmployeeID) + ' and was born ' + 
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), BirthDate, 126) FROM dbo.Employees
```

Comment: Ask Datacamp what they think is wrong with it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - it's a final exam so I can't ask them questions

Comment: In my experience, speculating about the reasoning behind some educational institution's teaching methods is generally unproductive.

Comment: I wouldn't lose any sleep.  If you're getting the desired result, that's that.

Comment: datacamp is picky about syntax you pop in the emulator. I was learning data science phyton and knowing full well syntax was correct still gave error. its not productive for new learner to be force confused. Real world you get a lot more freedom and most projects care about productivity vs syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`str()` left pads the employee id with spaces.  So:

```
select '|' + str(1) + '|'
```

returns:

```
|         1|
```

I imagine that those spaces are undesirable in the result set.  A simple conversion to a string is usually sufficient:

```
convert(varchar(255), EmployeeId)
```

Also, the time of the birthdate is probably undesirable, so I would just use the date portion:

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), BirthDate, 126)
```